# Can CrashPlan recover from two different locations?

Tags: macos, restore, crashplan, crashplan-central

My hard disk failed. :( Could be worse: I have backups (three actually). I know for a fact that the backup on my NAS is not complete and that the backup in CrashPlan central is very, very complete (I saw it finish the night before the catastrophe).

I don't want to restore straight from CrashPlan Central because I have lots of data and it's going to take weeks; but I want all my data, so I'd like to restore from my local NAS and then complement with CrashPlan Central. Is that possible?

My apologies if this is a trivial question. I haven't yet started the restoring process as the DVD of the machine also died so I can't install the OS on the new hard drive (geez!). I'm just trying to gather as much information as possible before I try the restore.

If it's important, I'm running Mac OS X.

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know, but you may need to trick Crashplan into thinking it's newer by making the NAS backup look older than the crashplan backup - explained here http://danilo.ariadoss.com/howto-change-date-modified-date-created-mac/

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Yes. You can restore from multiple locations.

You can cherry pick what data you recover and from where you recover it. When you click on the Restore tab in the CrashPlan GUI you'll see a pull down that lets you select the back up source to pull files from. And then you'll see the complete files that exist at that back up source.

You can choose to copy some of them or all of them back to your local machine's hard drive. There are options for which versions to restore and where to restore them to. By default it's 'Restore the most recent version to Desktop and rename any existing file'.